# Django Template - Cannot iterate throught this list and get menu item

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

i have one project andromeda where is 2 apps. 1 is blog and seccond one is blogmenu

but when I want to get information from the blog app there is no problem and i can get all information. but when I want to get a menu item from blogmenu I'm getting now error but there is empty navigation bar.

blogmenu urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('', include('blogmenu.urls')),
 ]
if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

blogmenu views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def Blog_Menu(request):
    Menu_items = Menu.objects.all()
    template_name = 'front/index.html'
    return render(request, template_name, {"Menu_items":Menu_items})
```

blogmenu models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    Menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Menu_slug = models.SlugField(name="სლაგი",blank=True)
    Menu_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="menuimages")
    Menu_url = models.CharField(name="url",max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "მენიუ"

def __str__(self):
    return self.Menu_name
```

sample html template code

```
{% for menu in Menu_items %}
    <li class="main-menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="main-menu-item-link">just text</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You mentioned about error! what is the error you are getting?

Comment: sorry i say i'm getting no error . because really i didnt get error just i cannot get items from database :((((

Comment: i have 2 application an using 2 views and 2 urls

Answer (score 0):

When iteration items in loop you should post something. You can do the below in your template.

```
{% for menu in Menu_items %}
    <li class="main-menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="main-menu-item-link">{{ menu.Menu_name }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: no thats not my problem. because when i tru iterate from blog post everything is working . i just can;t iterate though menu app wich is loaded in blog app views.py

Comment: when i add this.

        {% for menu in Post_list %}
        <li class="main-menu-item">
          <a href="#" class="main-menu-item-link">მთავარი</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}

its working

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you just forgot to use the object from the for loop.

This is probably what your looking for:

```
{% for menu in Menu_items %}
    <li class="main-menu-item">
      <a href="#" class="main-menu-item-link">{{ menu.Menu_name }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

If this isn't working either then I would suggest putting a print(Menu_items) after you make the query in your blogmenu views.py and see if your getting your data there.

Also don't forget to import your model in your views.py.